# test wraps below bullet ul li

Tags: html, css

As a requirement at work, I have to use someone's stylesheet and I'm having trouble trying to override one behavior. The unordered list elements `<li>` are having text that exceeds 1 line wrap around to the area below the bullet point. Here's the CSS that is causing the behavior:

```
ul
{
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;    
}

li 
{
  list-style-type: disc;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/CP32B/1/

What attribute do I need to override so that I can get the text to align like it does by default? (Example of default behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/B5jPH/)

Comment: wondering whether the answers helped...

Answer (score 1):

`list-style-position: inside;` is the property which causes that behavior and inorder to fix that, you need to use `outside`

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CP32B/2/)</kbd>

Comment: @user3629533 because you have paddings and margins set to 0

Answer (score 0):

Applying `padding:0` with `list-style-position: inside;` is hiding the bullets.

You can left align the bullets without text flowing below it by changing it to the following

```
ul
{ 
 padding-left:10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/CP32B/5/)

Answer (score 0):

> ul
>   {
>    list-style-position: outside !important;
>     padding-left: 2em !important;
>   }

!important will override the css