# Catch-22: I don't want my bullet points outside my div, but I also want the link text left-aligned

Tags: html, css

Alright, I already asked a question about how to get my link text left-aligned: [test wraps below bullet ul li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836491/test-wraps-below-bullet-ul-li/23836681?noredirect=1#23836681). The solutions involved changing `list-style-position` to `outside`. The problem is that I also want the bullet points inside my div. Is there a simple way around this?

Comment: ^ What he said... http://jsFiddle.net is possible.

Comment: @Paulie_D: http://jsfiddle.net/GX2yN/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D want my bullet points to be inside, like in the red list, but I also want my text to be aligned, like in the 2nd list

Answer (score 1):

Add padding to the contaning div

[**http://jsfiddle.net/GX2yN/3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/GX2yN/3/)

```
div {
    padding:0 25px;
}
```

OR

just to the `ul`

```
.outside
{
    list-style-position: outside;
    padding: 0 25px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**JSfiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/GX2yN/5/)